# Creating a camera-ready paper - keep text within specified area at bottom of page

Tags: vertical-alignment

I have to create a [camera-ready](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera-ready) paper. This means that I have to follow specific guidelines regarding text size. Of course I am using `geometry` package to specify the text area but I am running in a problem. I checked if text was typeset correctly, using `showframe` option and I found out that it is typeset outside of the text area. Not only horizontally, for which I don't really care, as I am getting an hbox warning, but vertically too. I mean that on some cases letters on the last line like "p", "g" etc are being typeset below the frame.

How can I prevent TeX from typesetting text outside the specified area? Should I tackle this problem case by case starting from the beginning? Would tweaking some TeX variables (constants is a proper name?) would help? If that is the case, which variables should I change?

### Edit

Here is an example. The lines are drawn by the geometry package. I'll try to make a mwe and I will upload it.

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: Would it be possible to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific as to the note that "[text] is typeset outside the text area." Are there words that TeX fails to hyphenate? If it's a matter of the last line of text on a page exceeding the allowable textblock, you can always reduce the `\textheight` variable (very) slightly so that LaTeX will set one less line of text per page.

Comment: Are there no margins between the text and the target camera frame?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Probably there are, but I don't know for sure. The instructions (which were obviously written with Word in mind) are specific that absolutely no text must be outside the allowed area.

Comment: `\setlength{\maxdepth}{0pt}`

Comment: @egreg thank you! This works great! Can you turn it into an answer? If you could elaborate a little bit on `\maxdepth` or provide some pointers I would be grateful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter `\maxdepth` states the maximum depth allowed for the last line of the text block (TeXbook, page 113); so setting

```
\setlength{\maxdepth}{0pt}
```

in the preamble should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Just to amplify egreg's answer and to present a MWE for the curious. The `\maxdepth` value determines the maximum depth of a page. If a page
exceeds this value, the page is moved up in a process that is very similar to the adjustment of
a reference point in a vbox when `\boxmaxdepth` is taken into account. To see this adjust the rule height in the MWE gradually from say 5pt-12.4pt and observe the output. Uncomment the `\setlength\maxdepth` to correct the issue.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\setlength\maxdepth{0pt}

\begin{document}
\rule{13pt}{12.4pt}

\lipsum

\the\maxdepth
\end{document}
```

You should see this at the left corner of the first page,

[image]

Comment: `\textgreek{parakalw!}.`